# How to rearrange UIImages?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

i'm creating a app where i'm adding some UIImages as subview of UIview. Now if I delete image I want to rearrange the remaining UIImages.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

This is what i have tried so far:

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) 
{ 
    id dict = [array objectAtIndex:i]; 
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100*i+100, 60, 60)]; 
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
    [imageView setTag:i+1]; 
    [ImagesArray addObject:imageView]; 
    [self.view addSubView: imageView]; 
}
```

Comment: please add some code, what you are try?

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Images can be re-arranged in many ways.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
    {
        id dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100*i+100, 60, 60)];
        [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [imageView setTag:i+1];
        [ImagesArray addObject:imageView];
[self.view addSubView: imageView];
}

Comment: I'm adding images like above. Now if i remove some image from that view  I want to rearrange the Uiimages.

Comment: the frame of Uiview to which i'm adding images is based on number of images. so when i delete image from uiview i need to resize uiview and also ineed to rearrange the uiimages. and if i add image back again the uiview should resize.

Comment: as per my suggestion you should use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) for grid view. it is very easy to add update delete imageviews.

Comment: remove particular image using removeObjectatIndex from array and call your method again..

Comment: My opinion,you should delete all photos in your view. You also should delete photo's index in your array and call again your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add You all Images in `NSMutableArray` and declare `NSMutableArray` in **.h** file.

```
self.imagArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.imagArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithName:@"image1.png"];
.
.
.
.
[self.imagArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithName:@"image_N.png"];
```

And you can easily manage it for add/delete image by `self.imagArray`.

If you want to delete any image then also write this code

```
[self.imagArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using array of images. Just remove the index once it's deleted and have a login to refresh the view.

Answer (score 0):

Init images to array first:

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) 
{ 
    id dict = [array objectAtIndex:i]; 
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100*i+100, 60, 60)]; 
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
    [ImagesArray addObject:imageView]; 
    [self.view addSubView: imageView]; 
}
```

Delete image:

```
NSUInteger deleteIdx = [ImagesArray indexOfObject:deleteImage];
[deleteImage removeFromSuperview];
[self relayoutViews:deleteIdx];

- (void)relayoutViews:(int)deleteIdx{
    for (int i=deleteIdx; i<[ImagesArray count]; i++) { 
        UIImageView *imageView = [ImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100*i+100, 60, 60)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of tag you can get the imageview which user want to delete .So you have to add TapGesture on UIimageView and you have to bind method for deleting image.Like this

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) 

{ 
    id dict = [array objectAtIndex:i]; 
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100*i+100, 60, 60)]; 
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView setTag:i+1]; 
    [ImagesArray addObject:imageView]; 
    [self.view addSubView: imageView]; 
}


- (void)oneTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    int myViewTag = gesture.view.tag;
    // Now with the help of tag you can remove object from you array and which you are want to remove and then you can reload you view 
}
```